# pymc3: Beta Distribution sd vs sigma

Tags: pymc3

I'm getting to know the lovely pymc3 library, and want to make sure I understand correctly. The signature for a Beta Distribution is `class pymc3.distributions.continuous.Beta(alpha=None, beta=None, mu=None, sigma=None, sd=None, *args, **kwargs)`. In practice, when using this in a model, you need to make the first argument be a string name for the distribution, but I don't see that mentioned here. More importantly, the documentation seems to state what all of the parameters are for except for 'sd'.

```
Parameters
alpha: float
alpha > 0.

beta: float
beta > 0.

mu: float
Alternative mean (0 < mu < 1).

sigma: float
Alternative standard deviation (0 < sigma < sqrt(mu * (1 - mu))).
```

It seems that I can define a beta distribution using alpha and beta, mu and sigma, or mu and sd. When I try to define a beta distribution using alpha and mu I am told `ValueError: Incompatible parameterization. Either use alpha and beta, or mu and sigma to specify distribution.` This also seems to ignore sd.

My primary question is, what is the difference between sigma and sd? I see very similar results when using them interchangeably.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/9c4b740f6dac7069c04cd051dc8b981b8f5dc76c/pymc3/distributions/continuous.py#L1219), one can see that the `sd` parameter is an alias for `sigma`. Note that if you provide both, `sd` will take precedence.

As for naming, this is inherited from [the `Distribution` class](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/9c4b740f6dac7069c04cd051dc8b981b8f5dc76c/pymc3/distributions/distribution.py#L29), which is the only one in the hierarchy that actually has a `__new__()` method defined. It's this base class that picks off that argument, and the rest get passed along to the `Beta.__init__()` method.